# Array.from() mapFn's array parameter invalid?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, built-in

Is the following behavior intentional when passing in a second argument — a mapFN — to `Array.from()`, or am I missing something?

I do understand the way `this` and method chaining works, but if Array.from() takes a map function argument, and that function is giving you access to each item and index of the array to be created, shouldn't it make the array itself available?

**item and index are logged as expected, but array is undefined**

```
Array.from({length: 1}, (item, index, array) => console.log(item, index, array));
```

**array is logged as expected**

```
[undefined].map((item, index, array) => console.log(item, index, array));
```

**array is logged as expected**

```
Array.from({length: 1}).map((item, index, array) => console.log(item, index, array));
```

For reference, my use case here was originally meant to be a replacement for the following code:

```
// populated array with dynamic length as opposed to push() in for loop
const populatedArr = new Array(numOfDigits).fill(0).reduce(digits => (
  [...digits, someCalculatedValue ]
), []);
```

Comment: Well, there is no array yet so the third argument of `mapFn` is `undefined`.

Comment: *"if Array.from() takes a map function argument, shouldn't it make the array-in-progress available?"* - Well the normal array `.map()` function doesn't make the *in-progress* array available, it makes the *source* array available. (Though I don't see why that same argument in the `.from()` map callback couldn't be set to the source object. But evidently it isn't.)

Comment: if you look at the Polyfill at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill - you'll see the map function is called with value and index only - I trust MDN documentation and polyfills to be accurate :p

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah that's a good point. But the normal map() also makes the item/index from the source array available, making the usage already inconsistent in this case, right?

Comment: The item/index in the `.from()` map callback is also from the source object. It's not the item from the new array under construction, because that item would be whatever your callback returns. So the only inconsistency is the undefined third argument.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ahh, right, I think you probably answered my question then. Feel free to turn this into an answer for an upvote.

Comment: Actually, on reflection, they're not handled quite the same. Seems the `.map()` callback is only called for array elements that exist in the source. The `.from()` mapping callback is called for all elements that will exist in the result, where the item will be from the source or `undefined` if there is no corresponding element in the source. (That is, their behaviour for sparse arrays or sparse array-like objects is different.)

Comment: @jabacchetta using `Array.from` on an input array is a bit of an anti-pattern; in that case, just use `Array.prototype.map` - although it works with array inputs, `Array.from` is intended for converting a *non*-array **iterable** into an array

Comment: @naomik Updated with intended use case. My original code works fine, just seemed a bit hacky and thought Array.from() made more sense, but unfortunately not for my specific use case.

Comment: @jabacchetta `Array.prototype.reduce` function parameter takes two arguments; can you show expected input and output?

Comment: "...More clearly, Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg) has the same result as Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg), except that it does not create an intermediate array. This is especially important for certain array subclasses, like typed arrays, since the intermediate array would necessarily have values truncated to fit into the appropriate type".  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from